# login PHP script showing an error

Tags: php, authentication

PLEASE dont comment on here telling me about my SQL injections, I already know :)...

Every time I use my login.html page (which is linked to the login.php file) the code generates the following message: 'Please enter a valid username and a password!' 
The code was working fine earlier so i'm not sure what i have done wrong ...

The code is below :

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","user_ben","password") or die ("Couldn't Connect!");
    mysql_select_db("user_phplogin"); //select database

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query))
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }
        // check to see if they match

        if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
        {
            echo "Youre in! <a href='members.php'> Visit your user profile! </a>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Incorrect Password! <a href='login.html'> Return to login page</a>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die("That user doesnt exist! <a href='login.html'> Return to login page</a>");
    }
}
else
{
    die("Please enter a valid username and a password! <a href='login.html'> Return to login page</a>");
}

?>
```

This is my form code...

```
<form action='login.php' method='submit'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='username'/><br>
    Password: <input type='password' name='password'/><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Log In'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Check if the password is hashed in the DB.

Comment: password and username are both in the database

Comment: Three else for one if cannot work.

Comment: why are you comparing username with the one from the row when you're selecting that row using that username?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code ? For example print both usernames and both passwords...

Comment: Looks like you messed up your form one way or another

Comment: { } doesn't appear to be proper in the above code. Is this the same one you are using? if so, try correcting them first.

Comment: @Mat thank you for the edit. I did not recognized that the else make sense

Comment: @NullPointer did you read the first line? Or add a *SCNR* ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you're sending a POST request? Maybe in your form you have a GET?

Comment: I will put my form in the above code

Comment: @BenJShapiro **PLEASE** spare us time by posting the full code next time ... :(

Comment: sorry @HamZaDzCyberDeV im new to this

Comment: Ok no advice about sql injection as requested. But `mysql_*` deprecation process has started. You know it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check like

```
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
```

it will check not empty also username and password is set

and

```
<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
```

since it [**default is `GET`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) (it mean if you dont type method it will be GET)

also you are using `method="submit"` there isn't any submit method

```
method      (GET|POST)     GET       -- HTTP method used to submit the form--
```

[**w3 form:17.3 The FORM element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)

Comment: where would I put the if statement?

Comment: instead of this  `if ($username&&$password)`

Comment: the form is fine i just changed the if statement and it worked

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<form action='login.php' method='submit'>
```

to

```
<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<form action='login.php' method='submit'>
```

to

```
<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
```

start login.php with this lines and answer:

```
<?php print_r($_POST);
```

and see what in the post